# How to add multiple mainwindows in one QMainWindow in QtCreator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmainwindow

I was kind of playing around and searching but nothing was useful. I've done let's say MainWindow1(using form, tabs, buttons etc) and I am currently trying to make "main" Mainwindow0 that will hold 3 or 4 instances of that previous mainwindow1. It's like having one window (that will control running) that includes 3-4 another windows. Something like shows the picture below.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called MDI windows. In Qt the "base" class is [QMdiArea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html).

Comment: As an alternative, you can use `QDockWidget`.

Comment: Thank you, MDI was exactly what i was looking for !!

Comment: QMdiArea is correct solution for you so now you can mark your question as solved and close it.